# Cannot enable side scrolling in Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

Is there anyway to enable horizontal and vertical scrolling for touch-pad in Ubuntu Gnome. Unfortunately I could not find any options to do so in the mouse settings.

Comment: This might be a little late, but can you tell me which files are in "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/"
You can type the following in the terminal:
    ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/